# How do the codes for the final Club Nintendo Platinum/Gold reward work?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, club-nintendo, nintendo-network-id

I am a platinum member on Club Nintendo, and recently Nintendo released their Elite member rewards for the year: downloadable 3DS/Wii U games. I own a physical copy of Animal Crossing: New Leaf, and that's also one of the games available for download. My Club Nintendo account is linked to my NNID which is linked to my New 3DS.

My question is: If I choose AC:NL as my reward, can I download that digital copy of the game onto another, completely separate 3DS? Is the download linked to my Club Nintendo/NNID, or is it a download code that I can use on another unlinked device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes will work like any other download code. They're not tied to an NNID or anything else, the same as other Club Nintendo download codes, so you are free to share the code with whoever you like. You  have to keep in mind, of course, that the codes are single use only, so once she uses it, no one else will be able to use the code.

Comment: Thank you! I'm kind of surprised that they are giving download codes like this, honestly. Have the CN downloads always been like this?

Comment: Yep, they've always worked this way. I have given a few to friends and stuff when there hasn't been anything I personally want.